# Yajra DataTables service implementation upgrade from Laravel 5 to Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, datatables, yajra-datatable

We have been using Yajra DataTables with Laravel 5 for a few years and have built up a library of over 50 of them, basically for the index page of a BREAD UI. It's finally time to upgrade, and  We're using the service implementation, which looks like this.

The current code is working against

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.0",
```

Here is the Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\DataTables\WidgetDataTable;
use App\Models\Widget;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Widgetaccount;
use App\Events\Widgetcrud;
use App\DataTables\WidgetHistoryDataTable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class WidgetController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('permission:widget_view', ['only' => ['index', 'history']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:widget_create', ['only' => ['create','store']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:widget_edit', ['only' => ['edit','update']]);
        $this->middleware('permission:widget_delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param  object $dataTable
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(WidgetDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('widget.index', [
            'title' => 'Manage Widgets',
        ]);
    }

    // other methods here

}
```

Here is the DataTables class:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class widgetDataTable extends DataTable
{

    /**
     * Display ajax rwidgetonse.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function ajax()
    {
        return $this->datatables
            ->queryBuilder($this->query())
            ->editColumn(
                'edit accounts',
                function ($widget) {
                    return '<a href="' . route('widgetaccounts.index', 'widgetid=' . $widget->id)
                        . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> </a>';


                }
            )
            ->editColumn(
                'documentation',
                function ($widget) {
                    if ($widget->documentation != null) {
                        return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-value="' . $widget->documentation .
                            '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary opendocument">View</a>';
                    } else {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'action',
                function ($widget) {
                    return '<a href="' . route('widgets.edit', $widget->id) .
                        '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" dusk="widget-edit-button-'.$widget->id .'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-remote="' . route('widgets.destroy', $widget->id) .
                    '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete" dusk="widget-delete-button-'.$widget->id .'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>';
                }
            )
            ->make(true);
    }

    /**
     * Get the query object to be processed by dataTables.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|
     */
    public function query()
    {
        $widget_id = null;
        if ($this->request()->has("widgetid")) {
            $widget_id = $this->request()->get("widgetid");
        }

        $query = DB::connection('dashboard')
            ->table('widgets')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'widgets.user_id')
            ->whereNull('widgets.deleted_at')
            ->when($widget_id,
                function ($queryvar, $widget_id) {
                    return $queryvar->where('widgets.id', $widget_id);
            })
            ->select(
                'widgets.id',
                'widgets.name',
                'widgets.active',
                'users.name as username',
                'widgets.documentation',
                'widgets.created_at',
                'widgets.updated_at',
                'widgets.deleted_at'
            );

        return $this->applyScopes($query);
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\Datatables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->can('distribution_manage_widget_lists_edit')) {
            return $this->builder()
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->ajax('')
                    ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
                    ->parameters([
                        'dom' => 'lBfrtip',
                        'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel'],
                        'pageLength' => 50
            ]);
        }else{
            return $this->builder()
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->ajax('')
                    ->parameters([
                        'dom' => 'lBfrtip',
                        'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel'],
                        'pageLength' => 50
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'name',
            'active',
            'documentation' => ['searchable' => false, 'orderable' => false],
            'edit accounts' => ['searchable' => false, 'orderable' => false],
            'last edited by' => ['name' => 'users.name', 'data' => 'username'],
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'widgetdatatables_'.time();
    }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@include('partials.panel-open', [ 'title' => "Manage widgets" ])
<form action="{{route('widgetsearch')}}"  method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class="search_button_group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
      <label>Search for widget-related Settings: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="required">
        <button class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary" id="basic-addon1" type="submit">Go</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
      @permission(('widget_create'))
      <a href="{{ route('widgets.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary" dusk="widget-create-button">Add New widget</a>
    @endpermission
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="text-right">
      <a href="{{ route('widgets.history') }}" class="btn btn-primary">widget History</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{!! $dataTable->table(['class' => 'table table-bordered','id' =>'widget-table']) !!}
@permission(('widget_create'))
    <a href="{{ route('widgets.create') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add New widget</a>
@endpermission
@include('partials.panel-close')
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Documentation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
@push('scripts')
<script src="/vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js"></script>
{!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#widget-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete"))
     {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var url = $(this).data('remote');
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'DELETE',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
         })
             .always(function (data) {
                 var count = data.count;
                 if (count == 0) {
                     $('#widget-table').DataTable().draw(false);
                 } else {
                     alert("widget can't be deleted as there are associated widget Account/s (#" + count + ") under the same. Kindly remove the widget Account/s first.");
                 }
             });
    }
});
$(document).on("click",".opendocument",function(){
    $(".modal-body").html($(this).data('value'));
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endpush
```

Now I've updated composer and am trying to use:

```
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.0",
"yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "^4.0",
```

And when I view the widget index, I get the ajax error dialog

```
DataTables warning: table id=widget-table - 
Ajax error. For more information about this error, 
please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

When I look in the Laravel.log:

```
[2020-07-24 10:30:55] local.ERROR: Call to a member function queryBuilder() on null 
{"userId":19,"exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function queryBuilder() on null at /Projects/my-app/app/DataTables/WidgetDataTable.php:20)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: App\\DataTables\\WidgetDataTable->ajax()
```

So, it seems that on this line:

```
    return $this->datatables
        ->queryBuilder(...
```

the `datatables` property is not set. So, I am stuck as to how to proceed, and have broken my entire application. Looking for advice on what to try or a guide on how to upgrade the Yajra service implementation without having to modify hundreds of files.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but as I myself was stuck at this point in the process of upgrading, I thought I would share the solution as the documentation lacks a bit of detail.

I only got to understand what to change after finding and comparing this example sheet in the documentation:
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/quick-starter

Further changes are then introduced in yajra's upgrade guide:
https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/8.0/upgrade

Changes to the DataTables class:

1.

```
   /**
     * Display ajax rwidgetonse.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function ajax()
    {
        return $this->datatables
            ->queryBuilder($this->query())
```

becomes:

```
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;

public function dataTable(DataTables $dataTables, $query) {
    return $dataTables->eloquent($query)
```

2. 

If you're ajax / datatables function contains the `->editColumn()` api, remove the `->render();` at the end. Otherwise html will be parsed as string.
3.

```
    private function getColumns()
{
...
}
```

becomes protected:

```
    protected function getColumns()
{
...
}
```

4. Return Object of the html function is now CamelCased too:

`* @return \Yajra\Datatables\Html\Builder`

to

`* @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder`

5. the getColumns() function now returns Columns as Array of Columns:

```
    return [
        [
           'name' => 'users.firstname',
           'data' => 'firstname',
           'title' => 'Vorname',
        ],
    ];
```

becomes:

```
    return [
        Column::computed('firstname')
            ->name('users.firstname')
            ->title('Vorname'),
    ];
```

For which you need to import:
`use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;`

Even though that's the new way, your way of returning columns should still work as well.

---

Actually that's all

Many things are possible with sublime's find and replace so it shouldn't be that costly.

I hope that helps someone else who is struggling with the update.

Cheers
Dominik